# Count Cells Depending on String in Other Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheet where I've got two columns; one of costs and one of the payer.

I now want to sum all costs pertaining to one person in one cell. I'm not sure how to do this in Excel. If it helps this Python code would do it in Python:

```
salvador_sum = 0
dali_sum = 0

for i in range(len(names)):
    if names[i] == "Salvador":
        salvador_sum += costs[i]
    elif names[i] == "Dali":
        dali_sum += costs[i]
```

Where costs is the list of costs, and names is the corresponding list of the names of the people who paid for them.

Thanks.

Comment: You got a google speadsheets, you have python code and you need an excel formula? I'll answer based on the title; have a look at `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: @JvdV confused? I am...

Comment: I would try countifs().

Comment: I'd suggest a pivot table. :)

Comment: Say I've got the names in D and the costs in C. I want to sum all costs that Salvador payed for in one cell, maybe F3, I feel like:=Countifs(D2:D999, ="Salvador", C2:C999) should do the trick (given Microsoft's documentation, but I get errors. @SolarMike

Comment: I need it to be done using Google sheets code. @JvdV

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I voted to close this question. It's talking about three different applications and you do not have Google Script code to start with. Have a look at [ask] a question with an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "select A,sum(B),count(B) where A is not null group by A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The below formumlas give you the **total cost per person** , `sumif` , and the **total occurrences of a person** , `countif` , please see below and let me know if this is what you're looking for:

```
C3 = SUMIF($A$3:$A$23,A3,$B$3:$B$23)
D3 = COUNTIF($A$3:$A$23,A3)
```

[image]

Comment: Say I've got the names in D and the costs in C. I want to sum all costs that Salvador payed for in one cell, maybe F3, I feel like:=Countifs(D2:D999, ="Salvador", C2:C999) should do the trick (given Microsoft's documentation, but I get errors

Comment: You need an extra arguement at the end, it should be ```countifs(D2:D999,"Salvador",C2:C9999,"Yes")```, or ```countif(D2:D999,"Salvador")```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Super strange. Also since I'm interested in the total costs, not how many individual costs someone's paid for I should be using sumifs, right?

Comment: Yes for total costs per person use ```sumif```, or ```sumifs``` dependending on whether you want 1 or 2(or more) conditions respectively. How come it doesn't work? Does it give you an error or just doesn't give anything back? Are there extra spaces in ```Salvador ```?

Comment: It just tells me #ERROR,

Comment: Got it to work using =SUMIF(D2:D999; "Salvador"; C2:C999)